# Matrix with roots of unity entries

Tags: matrices, reference-request, normed-spaces

For a given prime p, i am interested in the norms of matrices which have root of unity entries, i.e., $M_{k,l} \in \{1, \zeta, \dots, \zeta^{p-1}\}$ where $\zeta = \exp{(2\pi I/p)}$. Are there any studies of the norms of such matrices without the restriction to the matrix being unitary? I guess the DFT matrix has the least infinity norm, but how does the norm behave under change of entries.