# Is there an accepted name for a square matrix, each member of which has an absolute value of $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Is there an accepted name for a square matrix, each member of which has an absolute value of $1$?

Comment: Fred-matrix ???

Comment: No, there is no such accepted name.

Comment: Are the entries even [roots of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781749/matrix-with-roots-of-unity-entries)?

Comment: No special name as such: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones.

Comment: Over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

Comment: They come up in my work, I call them _flat_.

Comment: Over C. What field do you work in, Chris?